# Standard unit value for 3d game character height?

Tags: directx9, first-person-shooter, 3d-modeling

Basically I'm building a first person shooter game using DirectX9. And now, I'm working on the modeling side. But before I start modeling, I have to make sure that I create all the models with accurate size. So it doesn't look too big or too small in the game. But I'm having problem deciding the characters height value including the main character and the NPC characters. I think it would be easy to measure other models/houses/walls/doors size if I have the characters height. Otherwise, I will messed up everything.

I assume that all the characters are 1.8 meter in height, including the main one. Though not sure that how to represent that value in DirectX vector ( DirectX unit == ? ) but If I set the camera height that value, it looks too low from the ground ( in my eyes ). Now what is the next value? Should I switch to fit? Which would very big value like 6. Or is there any standard value for that case which I don't know?

I hope you guys have understand my situation. Actually I'm very new to this kind of stuffs. So hopping to get some help or suggestion which would be great for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no "standard," although for reasons of numerical stability you will want to choose some conversation factor between modeling and rendering units that keeps them small (don't make characters 10,000,000 units tall, prefer to make them more like 1 to 10 units tall).

Pick values that work for you, your pipeline, and your game. This means adjusting the modeling units (maybe on export) or rendering units (by adjusting projections and whatnot) accordingly until you find a balance that makes sense for your game and how you think about the problems space.

Comment: So, should I rely on my eyes in that case?

Comment: You can rely on the math if you're good at visualizing it in your head. Failing that, your eyes are a good tool to use. Adjust the parameters of your projection transforms, see how they feel, adjust scale and sizes, see how that feels. Find something works for you.

Comment: Ah... I have actually thought about that before but also hoped for the better...

Comment: Anyway, thanks so much for your great answer. Though in fact, I'm not really good at visualizing. So this is another problem...

Comment: Do you have any value in your mind that you may want to suggest me to use as FPS game character height?

Comment: I suggest using the same units as you model in, for simplicity, and adjusting the position and projection of your camera instead to try to find something that feels right before you start introducing scaling factors into your export. Beyond that, it is up to you.

Comment: If I recall correctly, Nvidia's PhysX physics engine uses a 1 unit = 1 meter conversion ratio for realistic physics and I assume other engines have a similar ratio. If you find a conversion that suits the engine you use (or modelling environment), you can use the average human height (1.58m for female, 1.70m for male) according to Google.

Comment: @MohammadShuvo FYI 1 Unit = 1 centimeter in Unreal Engine 4.

Comment: @Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov,Thanks for the information :)